# iOS, CoreAudio: Suspend during app loading kills CoreAudio initialization

Tags: ios, core-audio, suspend

My app uses audio session and audio units. The initialization of them is done in main thread in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and usually runs fine.

However, if one quickly suspend the device (lock screen) as soon as the app starts we get a crash due to failures in setting up some CoreAudio session or audio unit properties during the init sequence.

How to handle this kind of situation?

**EDIT:**
The "crash" was a custom assert whenever the `OSStatus` returned from setting properties was not `noErr`. So technically it was not a crash. Seems that `AudioSessionSetActive()` fails very often in the said scenario. But when I set a breakpoint right there when I assert (result == noErr), the breakpoint can't be hit.

My question was: is this failure by design if suspend is issued at that moment?

Comment: What kind of crash?  Logs? Code?

Comment: Where does the crash occur?

Comment: I updated my question. hope it clarify things.